# VBA: Delete everything before character including the character

Tags: vba, excel, command

I have excel sheet with a lot of data, that need to be parsed. 
It is a big project for me, managed to make it step by step so far, but something small is stopping me.
In one of my fields i have:

```
sadadasd|2|adsgfas
sadadasd|1|adsgfas 
sadadasd|0|adsgfas
```

What i want to do is for the rows that contain

```
|1| -> delete entire row
|2| -> delete everything before |1| including |1|
|0| -> Delete cell value.
```

I have the conditions for 0 and 2, but im missing 1.
I am currently using the following code:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Range("H4:H1000")
For Each myCell In myRange
If myCell Like "*|0|*" Then

myCell.ClearContents


ElseIf myCell Like "*|1|*" Then
myCell.EntireRow.Delete

ElseIf myCell Like "*|2|*" Then
  result_3

Else
End If
Next myCell
```

Can you help me replacing result_3 with a command for removing everything except the text in the back? I'm sure there is a solution already, but I spent too much time on that one, and I need to finish the project soon.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use INSTR to find the position and MID to parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove everything before the number 1 including the '|' chars.

```
myCell.Value = Right(myCell.Value, Len(myCell.Value) - InStr(myCell.Value, "1") + 1)
```

Btw from your explanation of the problem it seems that you are mixing the solution for `*|1|*` and `*|2|*`.

Comment: Hi Miguel, Indeed, i made a mistake in my explanation, but you got me right. However, thank you for the solution. It works perfectly, needed only to change two parameters

Comment: myCell.Value = Right(myCell.Value, Len(myCell.Value) - InStr(myCell.Value, "2") - 1)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, v As String, vv As String

    For i = 1000 To 4 Step -1
        With Cells(i, "H")
            v = .Value
            vv = Mid(v, 10, 2)
            Select Case vv
            Case "2|"
                .EntireRow.Delete
            Case "1|"
                .Value = Mid(v, 12, 9999)
            Case "0|"
                .Clear
            End Select
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

If your records are not fixed length:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, v As String

    For i = 1000 To 4 Step -1
        With Cells(i, "H")
            v = .Value
            If InStr(1, v, "|") > 0 Then
                Select Case Split(v, "|")(1)
                Case "2"
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                Case "1"
                    .Value = Split(v, "|")(2)
                Case "0"
                    .Clear
                End Select
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Gary, Thank you for the help as well. The code didnt work for me, i am not really sure why, but now It is okay. Thank you !

Comment: @AsenPanayotov Hey, I just answered your question on how to change the value of the cell, but Gary's Student implementation is something you should look at, his solution will solve an issue you'll have in the future (I didn't even notice until I saw his answer), when you delete rows in a range you need to do one of two thing or start from the last row has he did, or adjust the row count when you delete (which is more troublesome), for your macro to work as you intend you should use Gary's answer. If you have trouble doing so I'm sure either me or Gary's Student will be here to help.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu Hey, Thank you for your answer and staying in touch, and I agree with your opinion on Gary's solution. I didn't have time to explain much what am I actually doing but you guys helped me at the end of my project and saved me a lot of time. I am actually working at purchasing department of lighting busyness company, and I do really have a lot of data to analyze each day.

Comment: I made basically a system working beside SAP . This last part you helped me with saves between 2 to 4 hours of work to me and two more colleagues. More interesting it already gave an increase in the quality of service we provide to our sales companies and customers in only 1 day. I am quite new to excel VBA but if you have some struggle or you work on something or have an idea you want to develop with somebody, let me know. Cheeses